# Breaking up a product probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-sets

#### Context

Suppose I have two measurable spaces $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ on which we have two probability measures $\pi$ and $\nu$ respectively. I form a joint distribution $\mu = \pi\otimes \nu$ on the joint space $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z}) := (\mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{X}\otimes \mathcal{Y})$.

#### Question

> Let $\mathsf{C}\in\mathcal{Z}$. Is it true that there **always** exist $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}$ such that
> $$
> \mu(\mathsf{C}) = \pi(\mathsf{A})\nu(\mathsf{B})
> $$

#### Attempted Solution

Given any two subsets $\mathsf{A}\subset\mathsf{X}$ and $\mathsf{B}\in\mathsf{Y}$ (not necessarily measurable subsets), the **Cartesian product** of these subsets is the set of all pairs as follows
$$
\mathsf{A}\times\mathsf{B} := \left\{(x, y)\,:\, x\in\mathsf{A}, y\in\mathsf{B}\right\}.
$$
Now, if these two sets are measurable, meaning $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}$ then we call their Cartesian product $\mathsf{A}\times\mathsf{B}$ a **measurable rectangle**. Now, the sigma algebra $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$ is the sigma algebra generated by the collection of measurable rectangles
$$
\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y} := \sigma\left(\{\mathsf{A}\times\mathsf{B}\,:\, \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}, \mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}\}\right)
$$
This means that we have taken all the sigma algebras containing the collection of all measurable rectangles and then we have taken the intersection of all these sigma algebras. The remaining sigma algebra, $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$, is the smallest sigma algebra containing this collection. Now, the fact that it *contains* the collection does not mean that every set $\mathsf{C}\in\mathcal{Z}$ is necessarily a measurable rectangle, or is it? I want to try to understand this better since I constantly see
$$
\mu(\mathsf{C}) = \pi(\mathsf{A})\nu(\mathsf{B})
$$
in papers or books but it is not motivated.

If it is not always possible, then can you give a counter example? I am particularly interested in examples where $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X}) = (\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y}) = (\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$.

Comment: the statement is false. Take a look at the meaning of $\mathcal{X}\otimes \mathcal{Y}$. By example, do you think that all lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as a product of measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$? By example take a look at the graph of a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by example $x\mapsto \sin x$

Answer (score 2):

If one of the measures, say $\nu$, is diffuse, the answer is Yes. Given $C$, take $A=\mathsf{X}$ and $B$ any element of $\mathcal Y$ with $\nu(B)=\nu(C)$. The fact that $\nu$ is diffuse guarantees that $\nu(\mathcal Y) = [0,1]$.

**Example:** Take $\mathsf{X}=\mathsf{Y}=\{0,1\}$, $\pi={1\over 2}\delta_0+{1\over 2}\delta_1$ and $\nu={1\over 3}\delta_0+{2\over 3}\delta_1$. Then $\pi$  takes only the values $0,{1\over 2}, 1$, while $\nu$ takes only the values $0,{1\over 3}, {2\over 3}, 1$. Therefore $\mu\left(\{(0,1), (1,0),(1,1)\}\right) ={5\over 6}$ cannot be of the form $\pi(A)\nu(B)$.